# Terrestrial Flying Saucers

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read part of a novel in the 1970's where a secret organization or civilization on earth was had flying saucers and was trying to take over the human race.  I remember something about the saucers being made with a metal that allowed air to flow through it, and people being hypnotized by lights blinking at a certain speed.  The author was not a sci fi writer but very well known in other fiction genres.  Does anyone know what the title of this book was and who wrote it?  Thanks.

Comment: If your date is a bit off, there's W.A. Harbinson's [*Projekt Saucer*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1726142.Genesis) the first published book, *Genesis*, being released in 1980.

Answer (score 8):

Could be the [Projekt Saucer](https://www.goodreads.com/series/155457-projekt-saucer) series by W. A. Harbinson, This involved a group of Nazi holdouts at a secret base in Antarctica, who plotted a comeback with the aid of this weapon. The order of the series doesn't match the order the books were written, and you're probably remembering the book [Genesis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1726142.Genesis) that was written first even though it's the third in the series. Genesis was written in 1980 so just outside the 1970s.

The porous metal is described as:

> In order to get rid of the boundary layer completely – and in order to make use of the ‘dead air’ not only for acceleration but for maneuvering as well – what was required was a porous metal that would act like a sponge and remove the need for air intakes altogether.

The saucers are covered in flashing lights, but the light that causes the hypnosis is just described as a *beam of light*. When one of the characters (*Richard*) is describing seeing the saucers hypnotise a woman he says:

> Richard:
>   Because of the way the disks circled the car. Because of the sounds they were making. Because they shone lights into the car and the car began to shake and a beam of light fell on the woman’s eyes and made her act strangely.
>
> Doctor:
>   She changed when the beam of light struck her?

Comment: Hi Mike. I have the book so I've added a supporting quote. Please feel free to roll back the edit if you don't like it.

Comment: No that's fine. I've read the book but don't own it so I was gong from memory.

Comment: Note that *Inception* is 1991, a decade after *Genesis* (1980), which was my suggestion.

Comment: @MikeStone I've managed to pin down a copy of the third book in the series, Genesis, which was actually published first and it's almost certain the book the OP is remembering. It has the scenes where people are hypnotised by flashing lights. Shall I update your answer with this info?

Comment: Please do. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you people.  GENESIS seems to be the book, since when I found an image of the paperback on bookfinder.com it matched my memory of the cover art.